# Debain system Shortcut inside SH Script

Tags: linux, bash, debian, terminal, tmux

So I have a basic SH script that lanuches and splits TMUX.
I would just like the script to run either or Super+T or ALT-F10 after finishing all of the necessary steps for tmux. I have installed and tried both xdotool and wmctrl, but not much luck.

```
#!/bin/bash
tmux new-session -d 
tmux split-window -h 
tmux split-window -v
tmux select-pane -t 0
tmux new-window 'k'
tmux -2 attach-session -d
xdotool key alt-F10
$SHELL
```

Simple little thing but would love to be able to get it working with the window maximize. Thank you!

-K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are close, but:

- The key code is slightly off
- `xdotool` needs to run before you attach to the Tmux session, otherwise it won't run until after you exit or disconnect from Tmux
- Not that it is causing a problem, but the `$SHELL` at the end isn't needed.  It also isn't running until after you exit/detach from Tmux, so you just ended up with a nested subshell after exiting.

So this seems to work for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmux new-session -d 
tmux split-window -h 
tmux split-window -v
tmux select-pane -t 0
tmux new-window 'k'
xdotool key Alt+F10
tmux -2 attach-session -d
```

The `xdotool` invocation can really come anywhere in the script, as long as it is *before* the `attach-session`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the $SHELL clarification. it still doesn't seem to maximize the new window for me? I tried moving the xdotool order around as well.

Comment: @KyleJutras Very odd.  What happens if you just enter `xdotool key Alt+F10` at the command-line?

Comment: yeah it seems like it should work. It doesn't either from the command-line. So maybe I reinstall xdotool? Thanks again @NotTheDr01ds

Comment: Doubt a reinstall of xdotool is going to make a difference.  What's your desktop manager and terminal?  Wondering if it could be related to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/215543/432493).

Comment: Thanks so much man!! You were right it was the GTK issue. Changed desktop managers and the script works perfectly. Installed KDE. Everything is working perfectly!

Comment: @KyleJutras If you happen to see this, don't forget to accept the answer.  I'm less worried about the rep than the fact that questions without accepted answers will get auto-bumped months or years later.  Better to close it out.  Thanks!